# Calculate time difference in php

Tags: php, date, time, timer, countdown

I am trying to calculate time different between 3 different dates

```
1. Start date 
2. End date 
3 current date
```

I have been researching on how to calculation but couldn't find any exact example.

Any assistance in resolving this would be appreciated.

```
function getweekSartEndDate($date){
$cur_date = strtotime($date); // Change to whatever date you need
// Get the day of the week: Sunday = 0 to Saturday = 6
$dotw = date('w', $cur_date);
if($dotw>1){
    $pre_monday  =  $cur_date-(($dotw-1)*24*60*60);
    $next_sunday = $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60);
}
else if($dotw==1){
    $pre_monday  = $cur_date;
    $next_sunday =  $cur_date+((7-$dotw)*24*60*60);
}
else if($dotw==0){
    $pre_monday  =$cur_date - (6*24*60*60);;
    $next_sunday = $cur_date;
}

$date_array =   array();
$date_array['weekStart'] = $pre_monday;
$date_array['weekEnd'] = $next_sunday;

return $date_array;
```

}

The above is the example code i got so far, and i was able to get the start and end dates of a week as seen below:

```
$weekStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $weekInfo['weekStart']);
$weekEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $weekInfo['weekEnd']);
```

My challenges is how to get the time difference in `'Y-m-d H:i:s' date format` from the current time.

Comment: Can you post any code you wrote?

Comment: Why the examples you found didn't fit your case? For that matter, what is your case?

Comment: I edited the post, please go through it maybe you could assist

Comment: @lofihelsinki  I want the time difference between Start date, End date and the current time.

Comment: As posted in the answer, the easiest way is to use the unix-timestamp representation of the date and compare those. I.e. convert all dates to unix-timestamps and compare those.

Comment: Your calculations won't work on daylight savings week. It's much better to use strtotime and let it calculate "Monday" with "precious Monday"

Comment: @lofihelsinki any example please?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need basic knowledge on how to do number comparisons in PHP.
2. Convert your date strings to a [UNIX-timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

   `$d = strtotime("19/10/2016 14:48:21");`

   `// 1519646232`
3. When the dates are in UNIX-timestamp format, it's easy to compare them with any regular [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) as int numbers.

**EDIT**

Difference in seconds:

```
$diffBetweenStartAndNow = strtotime( $date_array['weekStart'] ) - time();
$diffBetweenEndAndNow = strtotime( $date_array['weekEnd'] ) - time();
```

Comment: since when `var d = strtotime("19/10/2016 14:48:21");` is valid PHP?

Comment: This doesn't really answer OPs question, does it? In my opinion this should be a comment.

Comment: @Andreas Your always free to edit, vote and flag, as well as contribute with your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentDate = new DateTime($currentDate);
$leaveDate = new DateTime($leaveFrom);
$difference = $currentDate->diff($leaveDate);
```

You will get result as follow

```
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 0 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```